# Ansible authorization with Azure AD to use Microsoft Graph API calls

Tags: azure, ansible, azure-active-directory, postman, microsoft-graph-api

I want to do API request to my Azure cloud account (want to reset password via API). I tried to do this with Postman and it works well using Microsoft Graph API.

My question is:
Is it possible to call this API's via Ansible AWX (Tower)? Like i have few cloud accounts and i have to change the passwords on them after running a playbook. I saw that there is uri module but how can i authenticate with this via token?

Comment: https://medium.com/@claudio.domingos/ansible-awx-from-scratch-to-rest-api-part-3-of-8-3adcf539031f  It looks like you can use cURL.  If so PostMan shows you what to do with curl

Answer (score -1):

Maybe another approach - moving to the `shell`/`script` commands execution? Uri module in result will not allow you to use access token - but that you probably see.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/script_module.html#examples
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/shell.html